# dropzone.js processQueue - requeue files

Tags: symfony, dropzone.js

I use dropzone with symfony form(many other inputs). When i call processQueue(), files are deleted from queuefiles and i can't call processQueue() again. How disable automatically deleting files?

Answer (score 1):

If QueuedFiles is empty we can add files to queue again:

```
  for (let i = 0, l = files.length, file; i < l; i++){
    file = files[i];
    file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED
    file.upload.progress = 0;
    file.upload.bytesSent = 0;
  }
```

Don't fortget to remove class '.dz-processing .dz-success .dz-complete' from .dz-preview container